# Configure IIS to rewrite IP Address to Site Name

Tags: iis, rewrite

So i've started my first web site from home, and I'm trying to get it up and running and google crawlable and the like, but I can't seem to figure out how to have my site name returned in the address bar instead of my IP address.

I've purchased a domain name for my site on Godaddy and then set it to redirect to my site.

When you type in the domain name, you get redirected to `http://0.0.0.0/default.aspx` (not my real IP obviously), and that stays in the user's address bar.

In order to fix that temporarily, I've set up masking on Go Daddy which keeps the URL in the address bar, but just shows my website in a frame.  This is fine for users visiting the site, however any kind of automated robot such as GoogleBot cannot discover my content because of the frame.

I've looked into ISAPI filters and server-site-rewriting, and the like... but I just can't quite figure out how to do what I need it to do.

Any simple suggestions or links would be appreciated.

[CherryBlossomBath.com](http://cherryblossombath.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly setup your DNS records on Go daddy to point to your IP. You need to set the A records.

EDIT
Man this should be simple. Just make sure you are pointing your domain to your IP using DNS not forwarding and it should work fine. Or call go daddy! They are great on the phone.

Comment: Can you explain a little more of what I need to do in the A records?  I'm looking at them now, and I can add one or edit my current one... the current one looks like it just takes the request, and then redirects it to my IP address... when I add one, it has three fields: Host Name, Points To Ip Address, and TTL.

Comment: Show us a screenshot

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot post an image on here unless you have atleast 10 rating.  I can however post a link to an image, and I will do that tomorrow (Monday 5/17/2010).

Comment: I voted up your question. Should give you the rep you need :)

Comment: lol that raised it by 5 X) you need 6 to post an image.  Oh well, posted a link anyway.

Comment: and then i guess it got removed 0_o

Comment: BAH! LOL! Answer someone else's question and get some rep...

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: I'm going to upvote you for helping me so much lol thank you.

Comment: omg... as soon as I get 15 rep so I can do so 0_o. Is it just me? or is this site screwed up more than stack overflow?  I feel like server fault is deleting my content.

Comment: lol I called go daddy and you were right in the first place X) I didn't have my A record set up right... I saw an IP address in my A record, and it looked like mine with the same initial octet, but on closer inspection, it was go-daddy's server IP.  Some 1 plz give this guy an upvote for me for being so patient.

Comment: Glad it worked out!